# Can I pass an ArrayList to an EL Expression?

Tags: java, jsp, el, jsp-tags

I know that I can pass strings and primitives. But how do I pass an ArrayList?

> Snippet:

```
<form action="select.do" method="POST">
    <p>Select Beer Characteristics: </p>
    Color:
    <my:select optionList="${applicationScope.colorList}" name="color" size="1"/>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an `ArrayList` the same way as you pass any other object and you access individual fields through `${list[i]}`. You can find more on `el language` syntax in this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html).

Comment: Can you help me to resolve the issue with the following question?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099216/how-to-resolve-the-javax-el-elexception-in-the-following-code